# Convert an array with n elements to a tuple with n elements in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, tuples

I have an array of elements (numbers in my case)

```
var myArray= Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
//myArray: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

and I want to obtain a tuple than contain all of them:

```
var whatIwant= (1,2,3,4,5,6)
//whatIwant: (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int, Int) = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
var tuple = myArray(0)
for (e <- myArray) 
{
    var tuple = tuple :+ e
}
//error: recursive variable tuple needs type
```

Comment: How are you going to use `whatIwant` when you don't know what type it is or how many elements it has? If the number of elements is not known, stick to `List` or `Vector` (not `Array`).

Comment: well, actually my input is a Dataframe converted to an array. buy you are right, better I asked the question with a list..

Answer (score 1):

The trivial answer is this:

```
val whatIwant =
  myArray match {
    case Array(a, b, c, d, e, f) => (a, b, c, d, e, f)
    case _                       => (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  }
```

If you want to support different numbers of element in `myArray` then you are in for a world of pain because you will lose all the type information associated with a tuple.

If you are using Spark you should probably use its mechanisms to generate the data you want directly rather than converting to `Array` first.

Comment: any way to make it dynamic for an array with n elements? lets say myArray= Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

Comment: You can add more `case` lines with different numbers of elements. But the type of `whatIwant` would be `Product with Serializable` so how are you going to process that?

Comment: @Woeitg you just mentioned your array is basically a dataframe row converted into an array, right? so you should probably know about the size of array. And if you don't know about the size, you should somehow change your input data, since there would be no more approach.

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements of a tuple is not infinitely superimposed. In earlier versions, there were only 22 at most. Scala treats tuples with different numbers of elements as different classes. So you can't add elements like a list.
Apart from utilizing metaprogramming techniques such as reflection, tuple objects may only be generated explicitly.

Comment: I understand your answer but consider sometimes you need to do something that is not 100% correct from the programming point of view but circumstances force you to do so. In my case, I am editing a complex code and it uses tuples so I need to fix it somehow...

Comment: As the number of elements cannot exceed 22, you can achieve it with an if else statement or a match-case statement.